# Какое-то странное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

"Покажите, правило, которое, запрещает, мне, ставить, тут, запятые." Если Вы егo найдете, то оно будет доказательством Вашей ошибки, а если нет, то мы просто признаем, что в русском языке можно ставить запятые где угодно. Но ведь это не так, верно? http://mathhelpplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=26048&p=139254#p139254

Comment: Вам - можно. Я разрешаю.

Answer (score 3):

В русском языке существуют 5 основных случаев постановки запятой. Перечислить?